# Perforce diff file against a specific changelist

Tags: diff, perforce

Is there a way to quickly diff a file(edited in my current work area) to same file submitted in an earlier change list in perforce ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can specify any revision of the depot file to diff against. For example, if that 'earlier change list' was change 1742, you can simply do:

```
p4 diff myFile.txt //depot/path/to/myFile.txt@1742
```

There are lots of ways to specify the desired revision of the file in the depot. Run

```
p4 help revisions
```

for all the details, or see: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/filespecs.html

Comment: It returns
`//depot/path/to/myfile.txt@99180 - file(s) not in client view.`

Comment: Just to be clear, you didn't literally put '//depot/path/to/myfile.txt' in your command, you specified the real filename you are interested in, right?

Comment: :) Yes..I used the real existing path.

Comment: To compare two different files on the server, rather than comparing a file on the server with a file on your workstation, you use 'p4 diff2', as in 'p4 diff2 //depot/my/first/file //depot/my/other/file'